# Regex to split a String with 2 delimiters, 2 times

Tags: java, android, regex, string

I'm trying to split a String that looks something like this -

`"Tomorrow - Cloudy - -3/1 "`

to

`"Tomorrow"`, `"Cloudy"`, `"-3"`, `"1"`

I know how to do it in two takes, first `string.split("-",3)` then `result[2].split("/")` but is there a regex to do it in one line? I've tried`"[-{3}/]"` but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: as a note - you need to split first by `" - "`, not only `"-"`

Comment: How about splitting on `" - "` OR `"/"`? OR is represented as `|` in regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following if it's always in that format:

```
Pattern: (\w+)\s\-\s(\w+)\s\-\s(\-\d+)\/(\d+)
Substitution: \1\n\2\n\3\n\4\n

Input: Tomorrow - Cloudy - -3/1 
Output: Tomorrow
        Cloudy
        -3
        1
```

Example seen here: https://regex101.com/r/Fhnawd/1

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple delimiters by using the OR operator "|"

So in your case it would be:

```
    String s = "Tomorrow - Cloudy - -3/1 ";

    String[] splitResult = s.split(" - |/");

    for (String result : splitResult) {
        System.out.println(result.trim());
    }
```

Results into:
Tomorrow
Cloudy
-3
1